# loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type method which has no callable log method

Tags: python

[image]

The column 'pop' is integer which should be okay for log function. Is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: please do **NOT** post images for code, edit your question to replace it with text

Comment: `.pop()` is a method of a DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using the `df.column` syntax as it can conflict with internal methods or properties, use `df['column']` instead. [`df.pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is actually a method of the DataFrame object.

In your case, use `df['pop']` to solve your problem.

Comment: I think `df.Column` syntax is fine though, with capitalized column names. In particular for quick data exploration (easier to type).

Comment: @9769953 yes, it can be useful, but this is nevertheless a practice not to encourage, let's not make it the default ;)

Comment: It works! Why I don't face same problem with `df.units`

Comment: @JamesLi as a general rule, always use `df['column']` this will prevent many issues